# huobi signature always return "Signature not valid": Verification failure

Tags: api, sha256, freepascal, secret-key

Trying to access accounts I receive signature failure.
My signature is exactly the same as the reply in this link:

https://www.devglan.com/online-tools/hmac-sha256-online
(base_64)

I use this routine in freepascal for the calculation:

```
function getsignature(StringToSign , mykey:string):string;
var   LHMAC: IHMAC;   
begin
  LHMAC := THashFactory.THMAC.CreateHMAC(THashFactory.TCrypto.CreateSHA2_256);  
  LHMAC.Key := TConverters.ConvertStringToBytes(MyKey, TEncoding.UTF8);
  getsignature := TBase64.Default.Encode(LHMAC.ComputeString(StringToSign, 
  TEncoding.UTF8).GetBytes() );
end;
```

The total URL for the GET() is:

```
 https://api.huobi.pro/v1/account/accounts?AccessKeyId=xxxxxxxx-xapikeyx-xxxxxxxxxx-xxxxx&SignatureMethod=HmacSHA256&SignatureVersion=2&Timestamp=2021-04-27T12%3A55%3A07&Signature=nypzWyIf5f%xxxxxxxxsignatureresultxxxxxxxxxxx%3D
```

reply from server is:

> {"status":"error","err-code":"api-signature-not-valid","err-msg":"Signature not valid: Verification failure [校验失败]","data":null}

Comment: (Thanks for correct formatting Tom)

Answer (score 0):

```
n := chr($0A) ;
pre_signed_text := 'GET' + n + 'api.huobi.pro' + n + '/v1/account/accounts' + n 
+ Ak + '&' + Sigmet + '&' + Sigver + '&' + Timestamp;
```

this is the correct text to sign. it works now.